# Clone de uma imagem

Tags: javascript, svg

Tenho o codigo que move imagens em SVG com o rato. Quando movo a imagem, assim que é largado, quero que apareça o seu clone, na posição que o primeiro começou e que tambem seja possivel move-lo. Tenho aqui um exemplo, com o codigo do clone que nao me funcione:

```
var newimage = document.getElementById('img').cloneNode(true);
```

Exemplo: http://jsfiddle.net/kpvgkrey/3/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Podes clonar diretamente quando "agarras" um elemento, no `mousedown`.

Nesse caso só precisas de uma linha nova:

```
ddData.element.parentNode.appendChild(ddData.element.cloneNode(true));
```

#### Exemplo: http://jsfiddle.net/ra4ega92/

Ps: juntei mais uma verificação aqui por causa de erros que estava a dar quando o clique não era numa imagem:

```
if (!ddData.element || ddData.element.tagName == 'svg') return ddData.element = null;
```

Comment: Isso mesmo, mas preciso depois de um id diferente em cada elemento para guardar a sua posição. E cria um clone a todos eles, mesmo aqueles que foram movidos.

Comment: @akm e que ID queres dar? qual é o padrão que queres seguir?

Comment: Preciso de guardar a posição x e y de cada objeto movido num array, menos daquele que esta na posiçao (0,0). Dos objetos ja criados, nao se pode criar mais. So se voltar a mover o objeto do topo.

Comment: @akm dá uma olhada aqui: http://jsfiddle.net/twsthyds/ é isso que queres?

Answer (score 2):

Você quase acertou, só errou na hora de dar o appendChild, você está tentando dar appendChild no body, quando deveria dar append no svg root, tenta o seguinte:

***HTML***:

```
<svg width="90%" height=500px id="svgRoot">
    <image xlink:href=/favicon.png id="img" x=0 y=0 height=20 width=20 />
<svg>
```

***Javascript***:

```
function clone() {
    var root = document.getElementById('svgRoot');
    var newimage = document.getElementById('img').cloneNode(true);

    newimage.setAttribute("x", ddData.initialX);
    newimage.setAttribute("y", ddData.initialY);
    newimage.style.position = 'absolute';
    newimage.id = 'novoSVG';

    root.appendChild(newimage);
}
```

@Edit: JSFiddle funcional: https://jsfiddle.net/ee2ss3x4/1/

Comment: Se colocares um exemplo do teu código a funcionar, torna-se mais fácil verificar se o mesmo resolve o problema e assim receber a merecida reputação ;)

Comment: Pronto, adicionei no edit :)