# Limitar o numero de clones

Tags: javascript, svg

Com o seguimento deste projeto, [Clone de uma imagem](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/55247/clone-de-uma-imagem),  queria limitar o número de clones e do movimento das imagens por exemplo através de uma variável (ex: variavel = 5) Quando por exemplo forem movidos/criados os 5 clones, nao poder voltar a criar nem mover. E alterar o cursor, ao passar nas imagens, para no-drop.

Exemplo jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/twsthyds/12/

Comment: E qual é o problema?

Comment: Não consigo parar de mover as imagens, quero limitar isso.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

É só adicionar uma condição na função `mousedown` no `if`:

```
|| position_souris_x.length >=5
```

Para colocar o `no-drop` basta verificar na função `onmouseup` se já tem 5 elementos:

```
if( position_souris_x.length ==5 ) 
{
    elem=document.getElementById('img1');
    elem.style.cursor='no-drop';
}
```

Veja aqui a funcionar:

http://jsfiddle.net/twsthyds/28/

Comment: Obrigado, como posso alterar o cursor do rato para no-drop depois dessa condição?

Comment: Vê a minha edição @akm.